# Trendline error in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010, pivot-table, trendline

I am getting a trendline error message in some Pivot Chart forms I created in Access. When testing these a week ago they worked perfectly but now I continually get an error. Any ideas on why the error is occurring?

Comment: Can you please update the post with Error number and or Error Description. What has changed since last week?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in my response. I am not receiving a specific error number or description.  I double checked the data and it all properly updated. I run a script that automatically pulls data from a few different networks and that is input into SQL Server which in turn updates Access. That is all working properly and the queries I use to populate monthly form pivotcharts are fine but the weekly ones are all showing trendline error.